# unclear regarding uploading of csv file in php

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

So I want to:

- upload a csv file which will contain a list of student numbers, one to each line (392232, per line).
- populate an array with the student numbers (as i already have a process in place of looking up ids from an array of student numbers and storing etc if they were to add students manually)

I have been lookin at a tutorial found [here](http://www.damnsemicolon.com/php/php-upload-csv-mysql).

however I am slightly confused with this:

`if(isset($_FILES['csv_file']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'])){...`

where does he establish `'tmp_name'` from?

anyway, if somebody could explain how I should be going about this I would appreciate the help.

many thanks,

**EDIT:** added progress of where it is not working.

```
if(isset($_POST['csv_submit'])){
    if(isset($_FILES['csv_file']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'])){



        //upload directory
        $upload_dir = "/ece70141/csv_files/";
        //create file name
        $file_path = $upload_dir . $_FILES['csv_file']['name'];

        //move uploaded file to upload dir
            // GETTING THE ERROR BELOW.
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
            //error moving upload file
            echo "Error moving file upload";
        }

        print_r($_FILES['csv_file']);

        //delete csv file
        unlink($file_path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_FILES` is a magic superglobal similar to `$_POST`. It's an array of every file that's been uploaded in the last request, and where that file is stored (`tmp_name`).

`tmp_name` is basically generated by the web server to let PHP know where they've stored the file.

You have the following items available to you in each element of the `$_FILES` array:

1. name (Original Name of the file)
2. type (MIME Type of the file, ie. text/plain)
3. tmp_name (Path to the uploaded files' temporary location)
4. error (Error occurred when uploading, 0 when no error)
5. size (Size of the uploaded file, in bytes)

From what I can see in your code, this will work perfectly fine and as discussed in comments, I think the issue lies in your HTML.

The tutorial that you linked to has an incorrect `<form ..>` tag definition. For file uploads, you're required to set the `enctype` attribute, below is what it should look like:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: ok, so if you look at my edit, I have added the code I am trying to simply see if the file is being uploaded. However it currently not getting where I have commented as I have tested.

Comment: Could you also post your HTML? I assume you've tried debugging the whole `$_FILES` array with `var_dump($_FILES);`? If this is empty it means you're missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute from your `<form ..>` tag. EDIT: Just looked at the tutorial, the HTML code there won't work as it's missing said attribute.

Comment: added said attribute and the code used I get this output `Error moving file upload`
`Array ( [name] => students.csv [type] => text/csv [tmp_name] => /tmp/php605NT9 [error] => 0 [size] => 16 )`, which going by the fact the size is 16. I assume the file is uploaded, however my code still wishes to display error.

Comment: The most common cause of this error would be simply that you don't have permissions to write to `/ece70141/csv_files/`, try a chmod of 777 on that directory via FTP. At least the file is uploading now...

Comment: thanks, that sorted the problem it would appear. Now just need to insert into an array which shouldnt be a problem. thanks again.